# What if my web API isn't simple CRUD?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have some questions about RESTful Web API best practices.

It seems the standard is to use HTTP protocols such as `GET`, `PUT` and `POST` to simplify the interface.

> GET /tickets - Retrieves a list of tickets
>   GET /tickets/12 - Retrieves a specific ticket
>   POST /tickets - Creates a new ticket
>   PUT /tickets/12 - Updates ticket #12
>   PATCH /tickets/12 - Partially updates ticket #12
>   DELETE /tickets/12 - Deletes ticket #12

But after spending a while developing my first API, I really don't feel it falls into such a tidy design.

My API supports adding or updating `LineItem`s, and the caller can add or update any number of those `LineItem`s at a time. In addition, they can confirm or cancel any number. In the case of adding and updating, a lot of additional related data is also being supplied. For confirming or cancelling, much less data is required.

So how does this fit into the ticket interface described above? Am I creating a bad Web API? Does the accepted standard allow for other variations? Any good links that discuss this?

Comment: POST /ticket/12/lines - create new line under ticket 12

Comment: You should probably know by now that asking for links is off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have methods on a class that do more specific tasks than just CRUD tasks on the whole object. So, assuming that your `Ticket` object also has line items, you might have a PUT call URI like:

PUT /tickets/12/LineItem?name=BLAH&address=FOO

In the code your method would then be something like

```
public class TicketController
{
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("LineItem")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateLineItem(int id, string name, string address)
    {
        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Obviously you'd put in your other methods there as well. You'd probably want to modify that so that your line item information comes in via the PUT or POST body instead of via the URI, but it's useful to show how URI arguments work as well.

However, if the `LineItem`s in question *aren't* related to `Ticket`s, then you should find some other controller to put them in.

Comment: Can you clarify why you used the `ActionName` attribute here instead of just naming the action `LineItem()`? Thanks.

Comment: Either should work. It comes down to developer preference and how closely your team sticks to coding/web api standards. So long as everyone understands that PUT == Update, you're fine and there's no reason to put that in the method name. But even then, if you're using Code Lens or some other tool to find the LineItem method then you don't see the [HttpPut] decoration until you get into the class. The Update just makes it a bit more clear what the method does. Unrelated, you should include the Ticket ID per @benPearce's comment. I'll amend my answer to show that.